# Is there a metabelian group satisfying the following conditions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a group $G$ satisfying the following conditions :

(a) $G$ is metabelian of class $p$, whose commutator subgroup has exponent $p$;

(b) $G$ has no abelian subgroup of index $p$;

(c) There is a maximal subgroup $M$ in $G$ such that : for some $x \in G$ and $a \in Z(M)$
$[a,x,...,x] \neq 1$, where $x$ occurs $p-1$ times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H = C_p \wr C_p$ with base group $B$, so $B$ is elementary abelian of order $p^p$. Then $H$ has properties (a) and (c) with $M=B$, but not (b).

So let $G = H_1 \times H_2$ with $H_i \cong H$. Then I think we have (a), (b) and (c) with $M = B_1\times H_2$ and taking $a \in B_1$.

Comment: right, you are my best.  Thank you.